# Delays on various parts of http requests - help diagnosing

Tags: networking, slow-connection

At our school we've been having some weird network issues and I'd need some help pointing me into the right direction to start diagnosing them.

The main symptom we're having is that browsing the web is *very* slow.
But it's not clear where it's coming from.
From the images below you can see that different requests can have a large delay in very different parts of the request life cycle.
(These are a subset of requests generated when going to https://www.hln.be/)

It seems I cant include images in this post (need 10 rep points), you can see the images here:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZZT.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPKQM.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLa91.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6Pw.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiC4h.png

The speedtest results seem normal.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2KvF.png

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Capture with wireshark and see if you can find something interesting in there.

Comment: Do a test run with only IPv6 and one with only IPv4, differences between those can pinpoint some potential causes.